# Makefile dependent targets based on current target

Tags: makefile, dependencies, gnu, target

I have the following code in my Makefile:

`Target0: Deps0
    Common Rule to build Target
 Target1: Deps1
    Common Rule to build Target
...`

My question is since all the targets have a common rule is there any way to combine the targets into a single target and specify target specific dependencies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Multiple Targets in a Rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Multiple-Targets) and [Multiple Rules for One Target](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Multiple-Rules) from the [GNU Make Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/):

```
$ cat Makefile.common
all: Target0 Target1

Target0: Deps0
Target1: Deps1

Deps%:
        @echo 'Making $@'

Target0 Target1:
        @echo 'Making $@ from $^'

$ make -f Makefile.common
Making Deps0
Making Target0 from Deps0
Making Deps1
Making Target1 from Deps1
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. I didn't realize I could have a recipe for the dependencies and a separate recipe for the rule for the same target.